# Chef - roles and environments

Tags: chef-infra

Beginning with chef and have difficulty in getting roles/environment setup going. Unable to figure out what I am missing.

```
     Cookbooks: nginx_webserver
          recipes: default.rb, config_test, config_dev

     Roles: 
          webserver
     Environment:
          dev, qa
```

Here is my role file:

```
     chef_type:           role
     default_attributes:
     description:         Nginx webserver
     env_run_lists:
         dev: recipe[nginx_webserver::config_dev]
         qa:  recipe[nginx_webserver::config_qa]
         json_class:          Chef::Role
         name:                webserver
         override_attributes:
         run_list:            recipe[nginx_webserver]
```

Here is my env list

```
        chef_type:           environment
        cookbook_versions:
           nginx_webserver: = 0.1.2
        default_attributes:
        description:         development environment
        json_class:          Chef::Environment
        name:                dev
        override_attributes:
              nginx:
        site_dir: dev.mysite.com # This value changes between envs
```

Here is my node_list:

```
        {
          "name": "chef-node1",
          "chef_environment": "dev",
          "normal": {
            "tags": [

                 ]
          },
          "policy_name": null,
          "policy_group": null,
          "run_list": [
            "role[webserver]"
           ]

         }
```

My chef-client output/error:

```
        54.149.131.42 Recipe Compile Error
        54.149.131.42   

        ====================================================================
        54.149.131.42
        54.149.131.42 Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
        54.149.131.42 --------------------------------
        54.149.131.42 could not find recipe config_dev for cookbook    
        nginx_webserver
        54.149.131.42
```

I am not sure how to get my config_dev and config_qa recipes in place on the chef server. I have included both to my default.rb recipe but i still keep getting this error. My aim is to call confg_dev recipe when its dev environment and config_qa when its qa. Any pointers please

Edit : 1

Ouput from cookbook show command

name:          nginx_webserver-0.1.2
providers:
recipes:
  checksum:    23978bdef70ea9a852e27d9489acdda1
  name:        default.rb
  path:        recipes/default.rb
  specificity: default
  url:         https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com:443/opscode-platform-production-data/organization-0ffe55465085b0ed5ec6cc4dc383888e/checksum-23978bdef70ea9a852e27d9489acdda1?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIQKPG2CTSTRVDO4Q&Expires=1477168767&Signature=8EUWtT1RJq1S6/N0nF00XV879fg%3D
resources:
root_files:
  checksum:    d5324dd6a872900fd6ee12c9628d9595
  name:        README.md
  path:        README.md
  specificity: default
  url:         https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com:443/opscode-platform-production-data/organization-0ffe55465085b0ed5ec6cc4dc383888e/checksum-d5324dd6a872900fd6ee12c9628d9595?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIQKPG2CTSTRVDO4Q&Expires=1477168767&Signature=KuzF07t3/Xnw3BA30PkcNbsnQf0%3D

checksum:    d14d45c195dccbfe56b358b71d2a6a6b
  name:        chefignore
  path:        chefignore
  specificity: default
  url:         https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com:443/opscode-platform-production-data/organization-0ffe55465085b0ed5ec6cc4dc383888e/checksum-d14d45c195dccbfe56b358b71d2a6a6b?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIQKPG2CTSTRVDO4Q&Expires=1477168767&Signature=8nlPR7LBWOQbn6C7CfCaNTieaqM%3D

checksum:    6528f8499102744b7616913a6cb225de
  name:        Berksfile
  path:        Berksfile
  specificity: default
  url:         https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com:443/opscode-platform-production-data/organization-0ffe55465085b0ed5ec6cc4dc383888e/checksum-6528f8499102744b7616913a6cb225de?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIQKPG2CTSTRVDO4Q&Expires=1477168767&Signature=0KRkWnrxasYQFhKaM0Kdqh79ltk%3D

---

EDIT - 2:

Cookbook/default.rb

```
     include_recipe 'selinux::permissive'
     include_recipe 'nginx_webserver::config_dev'
     include_recipe 'nginx_webserver::config_qa'
```

Updated metadata.rb to = 0.1.3

```
 knife cookbook upload nginx_webserver
 Uploading nginx_webserver [0.1.3]
 Uploaded 1 cookbook.
```

Getting same error. Also, do i really need to include my config_dev and config_qa in my default.rb? Shouldn't chef pick up these recipes automatically based on env_run_lists?

Comment: What does `knife cookbook show nginx_webserver 0.1.2` display for you?

Comment: shows a lot of stuff. Mainly about my two recipes - selinux and nginx. Is there any thing specific you are looking for

Comment: ideally the whole output so we all here can understand what's happening here, minimally if the `config_dev ` recipe is visible in that version

Comment: I added some part. But it does not show any info about my config_dev recipe

Comment: please add four spaces to the left of each code line to make it code formatting

Comment: do you have newer versions of the cookbook? does running this command for them have info about recipe you're trying to use?

Comment: Added cookbook details

Comment: Start with a simple use case, don't try to use all features at once.

Comment: Did you really upload the new version of the cookbook to the chef-server ?

Answer (score 0):

Your environment uses the version which does not have the recipes (given you've uploaded them in `0.1.3` as per your log):

```
    chef_type:           environment
    cookbook_versions:
       nginx_webserver: = 0.1.2
```

Please use `knife environment edit`, put `0.1.3` there and try converging the node again.

Comment: I did but still the same results. Do I need to include non default recipes in the default one. One other thing i noticed is that the version of cookbook shown in Chef-server (UI - Attributes) is still old. I did upload cookbook and did berks upload as well. Also, UI shows proper environment and associated recipe.

Comment: @f-z-N please attach screenshots of that